# Failling to create a JSON

Tags: json

I'm trying to create a `JSON` that contains one main `Array` then on that `Array` it contains three differents `Arrays` and inside of those it contains differents `Objects` the thing is that the logic that I've created looks bad...

```
{
    "FirstArray": [
        {
            "FirstItemThatIsAnArrayToo": [
                {
                    "FirstItemOnThisArray": [
                        {
                            "name": "xxx",
                            "search": "xxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "SecondItemOnTheFirstArray": [
                {
                    "FirstItemOnThisArray": [
                        {
                            "name": "xxx",
                            "search": "xxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "ThirthItemOnTheFirstArray": [
                {
                    "FirstItemOnThisArray": [
                        {
                            "name": "xxx",
                            "search": "xxx"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The thing that I want is that the `FirstArray` contains three differents `Arrays` those `Arrays` I didn't put on the `JSON` because it says bad typed but I would like to put an `id` and a `name` and then in the item inside of the `FirstItemThatIsAnArrayToo` add more.

Hope you can understand this problem, otherwise feel free to ask to me.

### EDIT

This should be the `JSON` (EXAMPLE)

```
Cars
  id X
  name Audi
       id
       name Audi R8
            id X
            foo
       id
       name Audi R3
            id X
            foo
  id X
  name Golf
        id
       name Golf R8
            id X
            foo
       id
       name Golf R3
            id X
            foo
  id X
  name Pew
       id
       name Pew R8
            id X
            foo
       id
       name Pew R3
            id X
            foo
```

This is how I think it could be done, maybe I've planteated this on a wrong way....

Comment: I'm sure what you're looking for?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh what?

Comment: _would like to put an id and a name_ where do you want this?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh on each item of the first Array

Comment: Can you edit and show what output you're exactly expecting?

Comment: Like this `"FirstArray": [
    {
      "id": "123456",
      "name": "Test Test",
      "FirstItemThatIsAnArrayToo": [...` ?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh See my edit

Comment: **How** are you trying to build this file? With code, written in another language? In a text editor, by hand? (If it's the former, if doing it correctly that language's JSON generation facilities should have the responsibility of ensuring that syntax is correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the data you gave us:

```
{
    "listname": "Cars",
    "list": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Audi",
            "list": [
                {
                    "id": "A",
                    "name": "Audi R8",
                    "bar": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "id": "B",
                    "name": "Audi R3",
                    "bar": "foo"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Golf",
            "list": [
                {
                    "id": "A",
                    "name": "Golf R8",
                    "bar": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "id": "B",
                    "name": "Golf R3",
                    "bar": "foo"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Pew",
            "list": [
                {
                    "id": "A",
                    "name": "Pew R8",
                    "bar": "foo"
                },
                {
                    "id": "B",
                    "name": "Pew R3",
                    "bar": "foo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Gonna try to parse it with Java, let's see if it's easy :)

Comment: what's the name to point to the first list? I want to get the name of all of the list items

Comment: @Skizo if you set `var json = ` that json object, you would access the first list (of all the car brands) by `json.list`. Then, if you want to access the list for Audi, you'd do `json.list[0].list`.

Comment: Ya but I've a method that reads the JSON and put it all on a String, then how can I get the first list I do something like this : `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("list");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonobject = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = jsonobject.getString("name");
                Toast.makeText(context, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }`

Comment: Oh you mean in java @Skizo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100996/discussion-between-skizo-and-jared-hooper).